# Memecached not found when using exec() in php

Tags: php, memcached, exec, command-line-interface

I'm using CentOS, and I am able to execute php via CLI from the terminal, but when I run the exact same command via exec(), and it appears that the Memcached class doesn't exist.

so this works:

```
~$ php script.php args
```

But this doesn't:

```
exec('php script.php args');
```

Anyone have any ideas why it behaves differently in these cases?

PS: I've tried specifying the ini file like this:

```
exec('php -c /etc/php.ini script.php args');
```

Comment: do a `php -i` in both situations, and compare the .ini files being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by reinstalling memecache... I'm not sure why or how that worked.